Disabling Flutter ElevatedButton is not fast enough
I have followed the examples on disabling the flutter elevatedbutton after first press, but its not fast enough.  Part of my onPressed makes a call to a backend server for data, but its somewhat of a long process during which time the button remains enabled for longer then I would like and it is possible it can be pressed again.  How can I get the button to disable the moment its pressed without waiting for state or data to return?
bool isClicked = false;

ElevatedButton(
  onPressed:
                                            
     isClicked ? null :
        () async {
             setState(() {
               isClicked = true;
             });
  await postData();
  //postData makes a backend http.post call to a webserver for json data

)


The idea is to don't do anything after the button is pressed, at this time the data is being sent or received from other outside source.
Look at the following example:
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home ({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  bool isPressed = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text(
            'Don\'t wait for sever response',
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('Pressed : $isPressed '),
            onPressed: ()async{
              if(isPressed){
                return;
              }
              else{
                setState((){
                isPressed = !isPressed;
              });

               print(await getData());
              }
            },
            
          ),
          SizedBox(height : 20),
          if(isPressed)

          FutureBuilder(
            future: getData(),
            builder: (context,snapshot){
              if(snapshot.hasData){
                return Text('Got Data : ${snapshot.data}');
              }
              else if(snapshot.hasError){
                return Text('error');
              }
              else{
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            }
          )
         
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
Future<int> getData()async{
  return await  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3,), ()=>15);
}

How it appears:

Once the button is clicked onPressed function does nothing, in that time the system waits for the coming data. hence the user can not initiate another request while i'm waiting.
btw: it's preferable to deal with separation of logic, state manager can call PostData method for you (don't call it in onPressed)  to not be forced to mark onPressed as async. All works but it's a preference.
Hope it helps you.
